# Python Pandas - how to apply boolean series to extract rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a boolean series that I got from using .duplicated.  I'm trying to figure out what rows of my dataframe are returning True (and what the data is in those rows).  How can I use this boolean series to extract those rows?

Thanks - KC

EDIT- Data sample:

```
level_0 index   ID       date_time      value
54967   54967   54967   1/06/2016 19:30  1.00 
54968   54968   54968   1/06/2016 19:30  2.00 
54969   54969   54969   1/06/2016 19:43  3.00 
54970   54970   54970   1/06/2016 19:46  4.00
```

Want to return this:

```
level_0 index   ID       date_time      value
54967   54967   54967   1/06/2016 19:30  1.00 
54968   54968   54968   1/06/2016 19:30  2.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `keep=False` parameter when calling `.duplicated()`

```
df[df.duplicated(subset='date_time', keep=False)]
```

Test:

```
In [53]: df
Out[53]:
   evel_0  index     ID           date_time  value
0   54967  54967  54967 2016-01-06 19:30:00    1.0
1   54968  54968  54968 2016-01-06 19:30:00    2.0
2   54969  54969  54969 2016-01-06 19:43:00    3.0
3   54968  54968  54968 2016-01-06 19:30:00    5.0
4   54970  54970  54970 2016-01-06 19:46:00    4.0

In [54]: df[df.duplicated(subset='date_time', keep=False)]
Out[54]:
   evel_0  index     ID           date_time  value
0   54967  54967  54967 2016-01-06 19:30:00    1.0
1   54968  54968  54968 2016-01-06 19:30:00    2.0
3   54968  54968  54968 2016-01-06 19:30:00    5.0
```

Comment: Quick followup, probably just as easy. How can I retrieve all the rows that have the duplicated value.  so my duplicated value turned out to be (thanks to you) 2016-06-01 19:30:00.    So i want to retrieve all rows where date_time = 2016-06-01 19:30:00

Comment: @keynesiancross, `df[dups]` - will return you __all__ rows containing duplicated values

Comment: hmm..  weird.  But its only returning one row?

Comment: @keynesiancross, could you try to post a reproducible sample data set?

Comment: Give me one sec, let me try to rip out the data.

Comment: @keynesiancross, i've updated my answer - please check